# Swagger UI: Multiple anonymous objects in array

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

I am writing Swagger documentation for an API, and one endpoint returns many nested objects and parameters.

There is one returned array, however, which does not return regular parameters. Instead, it returns two anonymous objects that hold the parameters.

```
"balanceDisplaySettings": [ 
  {
    "type": "Balance",
    "label": "Current",
    "visible": true,
    "primary": false
  },
  {
    "type": "AvailableBalance",
    "label": "Available",
    "visible": true, 
    "primary": true
  }
]
```

YAML

```
swagger: '2.0'
schemes:
 - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
"/Path/":
     responses:
     '200':
      description: OK
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          balanceDisplaySettings:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
              properties:
                type:
                  type: "Balance"
                  description: description
                label: 
                  type: "Available"
                  description: description
                visible:
                  type: boolean
                  description: description
                primary:
                  type: boolean
                  description: description
              type: object
              properties:
                type:
                  type: "AvailableBalance"
                  description: description
                label: 
                  type: "Available"
                  description: description
                visible: 
                  type: boolean
                  description: description
                primary:
                  type: boolean
                  description: description
```

Looking at swagger's documentation for Describing Request Body, there is seemingly no way to handle objects without a name.

How do I (Using YAML) document this type of response body in Swagger-UI?

Answer (score 10):

An array of objects is defined like this:

```yaml
type: array
items:
  type: object
  properties:
    prop1:
      type: string
    prop2:
      type: integer
    # etc.
```

In your example, the response contains an object with the property `balanceDisplaySettings`, and this property contains an array of objects. This can defined as follows:

```yaml
paths:
  /Path:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              balanceDisplaySettings:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    type:
                      type: string
                    label: 
                      type: string
                    visible:
                      type: boolean
                    primary:
                      type: boolean
```

Note that the schema defines the response *structure*, meaning you don't need to specify the actual values (`"Balance"`, `"AvailableBalance"`, etc.) anywhere. However, if you want to display the example from your post (array with 2 objects) as an example in Swagger UI, you can add it like this:

```yaml
              balanceDisplaySettings:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    type:
                      type: string
                    label: 
                      type: string
                    visible:
                      type: boolean
                    primary:
                      type: boolean
                example:            # <-- example of array of 2 objects
                  - type: Balance
                    label: Current
                    visible: true
                    primary: false
                  - type: AvailableBalance
                    label: Available
                    visible: true
                    primary: true
```

Finally, you may want to split the inline nested schema to make the spec more modular.

```yaml
paths:
  /Path:
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/MyResponseObject'
                                    #   |
definitions:                        #   |
  # TODO: better name               #   |
  MyResponseObject:    # <--------------+
    type: object
    properties:
      balanceDisplaySettings:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/BalanceDisplaySetting'
        example:                     #  |
          - type: Balance            #  |
            label: Current           #  |
            visible: true            #  |
            primary: false           #  |
          - type: AvailableBalance   #  |
            label: Available         #  |
            visible: true            #  |
            primary: true            #  |
                                     #  |
  BalanceDisplaySetting:     # <--------+
    type: object
    properties:
      type:
        type: string
        example: Balance
      label:
        type: string
        example: Current
      visible:
        type: boolean
      boolean:
        type: boolean
```

Comment: I'm getting the error "Duplicated mapping key" in the online Swagger Editor when adding multiple objects to the array

Comment: @ChuckFecht, can you post the YAML code you're using? (e.g. update this question or post a new one)

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @ChuckFecht, your spec is not valid and indentations are wrong. I updated the answer.

Comment: I'm trying to use multiple objects in an array, not just one. The problem is using more than one results in the error `Duplicated mapping key`

Comment: @ChuckFecht, the "array of objects" schema in my answer is for multiple objects in an array. Do you maybe mean you want to _display an example_ with two objects in Swagger UI?

Comment: Possibly? Yes this is placed in the example value/model part of Swagger UI

Comment: @ChuckFecht, OK I updated the 3rd and 4th code examples to include example values for an array of 2 objects. Check if this is what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is the `oneOF` parameter.
With it you can use multiple anonymous objects as you want.

Just create some definitions and call them inside `items`:

```
"type": "array",
"items": {
  "oneOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Schema1" },
    { "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Schema2" }
  ]
}
```

You can read more about here:

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Can-You-Define-a-Response-Consisting-of-an-Array-With-Two/td-p/186919

Hope it helps

Comment: That's pretty worked for me.